# VM2289:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>)

Tags: jquery, sql-server, jsp

Hello friends i am totaly new to jquery please help me.
I have two jsp files "index.jsp" and "DatabaseFile.jsp". I have to fetch database data in "databasfile.jsp" and send this data onto the "index.jsp" page and display FName , LName ,Contactno in separate textboxes  in "index.jsp".For this purpose i have used $.post() of jquery in "index.jsp" page

this is code of jquery in "index.jsp"

```
$('.confirm').click(function(){
        var no = $('#id').val();
        $.post("DatabaseFile.jsp",{number:no},function(data)
            {
                var newdata = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(newdata, function(i, element) 
                    {
                        console.log(element.fname);
                    });

                $('#id').val('');
            });
});
```

this is code of "databasefile.jsp"

```
int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("number"));

    try{
    String query1   =   "select count(*) as total from Details where ID ='"+ 
    id +"'";
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(query1);
    int ttl=0;
    if(rs.next())
    {               
        ttl=rs.getInt("total");
    }

    if(ttl<1){out.print("Record Does Not Exists");}
    else
    {
    String query2   =   "select * from Details where ID ='"+ id +"'";
    rs=st.executeQuery(query2);
    String fn,ln,m;
    while(rs.next())
    {               
        fn=rs.getString("FName");
        ln=rs.getString("LName");
        m=rs.getString("Contactno");

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        obj.put("fname",fn);
        obj.put("lname",ln);
        obj.put("mobile",m);
    }
    }

}
catch(SQLException se)
 {
   out.println("SQLException : "+se.getMessage());
 }

I have used this code but it is showing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end 
of JSON input
at Function.parse [as parseJSON] (<anonymous>) at line 
" var newdata = $.parseJSON(data); "
in jquery $.post() method
```

Comment: Did you debug and check what value is being returned as JSON? Can you share that value here?

Comment: i dont know how to check it this is my first time with json..sorry bro please help

Comment: Do you know how to debug java code? Which code editor you are using? Try to alert the data before you parse it.

Comment: i am using eclipse

Comment: Did you debug the code?